# Why can I not manipulate data from this ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sending an ajax call to my json server on localhost:3000 and trying to get an object back to manipulate and display on a webpage. No matter what I do, I cannot seem to console log (data) in order to work with the object.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
    <input id="title" placeholder="Blog Title">
    <br>
    <input id="body" placeholder="Post Body">
    <br>
    <button onclick="request()">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="comments"></div>
<div id="posts"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As well as my Javascript:

```
"use strict";

function request() {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "http://localhost:3000",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm sure what I'm doing wrong here is something simple. I've referred to many web pages for more information such as https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options, https://github.com/typicode/json-server, as well as other stack overflow questions.

Comment: Any errors in your console? How are you opening the HTML page; via `http://` or `file:///`? Have you tried adding an `error` callback to your `$.ajax()` options?

Comment: What does your `.json` file look like? Doesn't look like json-server typically supports a `/` route

Comment: I'm running localhost:3000 in another tab in chrome, with the JSON server running in the terminal with the json-server --watch db.json command. The db.json file is just one post of json. All I'm looking to do is get an object back I can manipulate for viewing on the html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some information in your JQuery AJAX call check below example, Also make sure you are calling the correct API path as for **json-server** if you need to get posts you should call `http://localhost:3000/posts` on `url` not `http://localhost:3000`.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", // Define the HTTP method to use for the request
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/ip",
    success: function (result) { 
        // On call success
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
    , error: function (result) {
        // On call error
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    failure: function (result) {
        // On call failure
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It should be type GET by default. I've just realized Webstorm through intelliJ also validates the success:, error:, and failure: options by putting square brackets around the values. About to try JSON.stringify.

Comment: `GET by default` yes, I think your main issue in `url` try `http://localhost:3000/posts`

Answer (score -1):

You need to add some informations to your ajax call:

- `type` of call (post, get)
- reachable `url` with your script
- `data` you want to send

Example:

```
function request() {
    $.ajax({
        // add 'post' type if your getting data with $_POST
        type : 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        // be sure that your script is reachable from this url
        url: "http://localhost:3000",
        // you need to add data to send to given url
        data: {
            title: $('#title').val(),
            body: $('#body').val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually just trying to use GET to get an object to work with from the server, but this helps for the POST method I'm working on now.

My mistake was not saying http://localhost:3000/posts for the URL, as just saying http://localhost:3000 was being handled by the error: option. when using the posts URL, the success: option is utilized.